# Are the projection morphisms from a product of varieties necessarily open?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, ac.commutative-algebra

If C and D are irreducible, affine varieties over an algebraically closed field, and I form the product variety CxD, is the projection morphism from CxD to C necessarily an open map?  That is, is the projection of each Zariski open subset of CxD necessarily Zariski open in C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. More generally, flat morphisms locally of finite presentation are universally open (EGA IV<sub>2</sub>, Théorème 2.4.6).